# To get Numeric value from a alphanumeric String in PHP?

Tags: php, string

i want a function or a code to get numeric value from the string whose value is "2008 Revenue $5,700,390,000". the output that i want is $5,700,390,000.

Comment: Is the string '2008 Revenue' fixed?  Will the numeric always be fixed in as well?

Comment: So you want to get money amounts of the format `$…` from strings?

Comment: @SilentGhost :- i have tried str_replace() function by removing the non numeric values. But by that i will get 2008 back, which was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're absolutely certain the string will always be formatted as YEAR TYPE VALUE with spacings between the values you could:

```
$str = "2008 Revenue $5,700,390,000";

$exploded = explode(" ", $str);

$my_value = $exploded[2];
```

Comment: In addition to matiasf's solution, there are many ways this can be done simply with php's string functions. For instance:  my_value = strrchr($str, '$');

Answer (score 1):

This may be a good use of [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) ([how to with PHP](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php)).

The expression `\$[\d,]+` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hybrid using the built-in "floatval()" function and a regular expression - this deals with more complex strings.

```
function floatvalue($value) {
     return floatval(preg_replace('#^([-]*[0-9\.,\' ]+?)((\.|,){1}([0-9-]{1,2}))*$#e', "str_replace(array('.', ',', \"'\", ' '), '', '\\1') . '.\\4'", $value));
}
```

If you have more simple situations "32121.54BLAH" for example, floatval() will handle these without assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I only know C#, but I would use a Regex, like [\$.0-9]+ in its simplest form. If you need culture awareness (e.g. different currency symbols) you need to add more logic. Hope this helps.